# Trying to get sum of all UIDs in a column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column in an excel spreadsheet which holds comma delimited user ids. I have been reading and reading to try and come up with a way to do this.
I was hoping there was a formula I could use to give me a count of he UIDs.
Any help would be extremely appreciated.

[image: Excel Layout]

Answer (score 1):

This was accomplished using:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&D2&"*" )
```